# Using Savefiledialog to export Listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, visual-studio-2019, savefiledialog

I'm using a savefiledialog to export a listbox into a .txt file or a .csv file. I've set the SFD under pressure of a button and it seems to work properly until I try to save the file, when I receive the following error:

[image: Error while saving]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt*)|*.txt|CSV Files (*.csv*)|*.csv"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Using writer = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
            For Each o As Object In Form3.ListBox1.Items
                writer.WriteLine(o)
            Next
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

How could I solve? Thanks all are gonna answer me. Best regards

Comment: Did you set `.CheckFileExists = true`? Also, see [ListBox.GetItemText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext)

Comment: I setted CheckFileExist as true after Filter line but I'm getting the same issue. How could I set ListBox.GetItemText()?

Comment: That was a question, not a suggestion :) Set it to `false`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misundestood you. Now it's working perfectly! :) How could I save in the same file the value of two listboxes, separed by comma?

Comment: Your question has exactly zero to do with exporting anything or `ListBoxes`. A `SaveFileDialog` is simply a UI for selecting a file path. Your question is about selecting an existing file. That's it, that's all. Asking an additional question that is totally unrelated to that in a comment is not on. If you have a new question, post a new question. You need to be able to show that you've made some effort on your own behalf to solve the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on my side, you need to delete the `form3` before `ListBox1.Items`. I think that is why. I tried everything possible. Hope this helps.